# Динамическая генереация RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня получилось сгенерировать TabPage, вместе с RichTextBox в который загружается текст из файла.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TabCreate();
    }


    public void TabCreate()
    {
        RichTextBox box = new RichTextBox();
        box.Location = new Point(5, 5);
        box.Name = "richTextBox1";
        box.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        box.LoadFile("C:\\1.txt", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
        TabPage tb = new TabPage("Test");
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tb);
        tb.Controls.Add(box);
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        File.AppendAllText(@"C:\\1.txt", "Hello World" + Environment.NewLine);

    }
```

Потом я создал `button1` и `textbox1`, их задача добавить текст в файл который загружает сгенерированный `richTextBox1`, т.е сюда `C:\\file_1.txt`.

Но проблема в том, что я не знаю правильно его обновить richTextBox1 ?

Может просто у меня не правильная логика..

Сама суть в том, что я хочу генерировать `richtextbox` на основе к примеру 2 лежащих в папке файлов, а потом переходить по вкладкам и редактировать, сохранять текст. Вот и все, но пока что остановился над этой проблемой..

Просто помогите, и скажите что почитать по этому поводу.

Comment: Как-как обновить, перечитайте файл заново. `box.LoadFile("C:\\1.txt", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);`

Comment: Каким способом ?, в загрузке формы, включена, генерация одного таба, с боксом, при генериции таба, идет загрузка файла. Но обратится просто к загрузке с помощью кнопки КАК ? и вообще именно этому сгенерированному richTextBox1? вне функции его генерации ? Я пробовал после нажатия кнопки и добавление текста выполнять функцию  TabCreate(); Но, тогда генерируется ВТОРОЙ таб уже с новым текстом, а мне нужно что бы обновился только тот что существует без добовление нового.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, так. Убрать функцию `button1_Click`, и написать вместо неё замыкание:

```
button1.Click += (sender, args) =>
    {
        File.AppendAllText(filename, "Hello World" + Environment.NewLine);
        box.LoadFile(filename, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
    };
```

Comment: Спасибо, я новичек, и до таких функций как вы привели выше еще не дочитал ) но так как вы написали, работает. А можно каким то образом сделать так, что бы без кнопки ?, к примеру я пишу что то в боксе, и он автоматически сохраняет текст в файл ? (т.е в будущем я хочу сделать так, сгенерировать 2,3 бокса, в которых будут подгружены файлы, которые можно редактировать через эти боксы)

Comment: @wwwsubitoit: Да, можно, точно так же. Навесьте обработчик в виде лямбды на нажатие клавиши. Но я не советовал бы сохранять на _каждом_ нажатии клавиши (будет жутко тормозить), а сделать кнопку «сохранить». PS: лямбда — это функция вида `(arg) => { ... }`. Обязательно почитайте про них, без них никуда.

Comment: Просто я скажем, прыгнул в болото, и все делаю походу действий.. знаю что так нельзя но пока что так. Как я понял в полной картине, мне нужно генерировать при загрузке формы, таб, бокс, и кнопку, которая будет сохранять изменение таба. Только что сделал, боже как оказалось все просто, а я в такие дебри залез, но не без пользы как говорится. Про лямбды почитаю, и вобще изначально почитаюс с самого начала все, а не по ходу событий как в моем случае.. (Вопрос, как вобще имет доступ к генерируемым данным ? допустим к richtextbox вне функции генерации ? А так спасибо ! помогли очень :)

Comment: @wwwsubitoit: Удачи! Тяжело в учении — легко во втором проекте! Доступ к данным точно так же — вы можете у текстбокса просто попросить его текст в виде строки, и делать с ним что угодно.